# Using when with objects in array in Yup

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

I have the following object:

```js
const values = {
  people: [
    {
      name: "Mark",
      age: null
    },
    {
      name: "Shark",
      age: 31
    }
  ],
  isAgeRequired: false
};
```

When `isAgeRequired` flips to `true`, in my Yup schema I would like to make the `age` value for each object in the `people` array require.

I have the following yup schema definition, but right now it seems to validate successfully even if the above requirements are not met:

```js
const validator = object({
  people: array(
    object({
      name: string().required(),
      age: number()
        .nullable()
        .when("isAgeRequired", {
          is: true,
          then: (schema) => schema.required()
        })
    })
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `parent` context is not available in `.when`, so one way to get around this was to "lift" the `.when` condition so that it is declared at a level where `isAgeRequired` is a sibling like so:

```js
// Declare the default person schema separately because I'll want to reuse it.
const person = {
    name: string().required(),
    age: number().nullable()
}

const validator = object({
  people: array(
    object(personSchema)
  ).when('isAgeRequired', (isAgeRequired, schema) => {
    if (isAgeRequired) {
     return array({
      ...personSchema,
      age: personSchema.age.required() // Override existing age rule and attach .required to it
     })
    }
    
    return schema;
  })
});
```